# Android-studio 3.5.1 Gradle ERROR: No value has been specified for property lottie-react-native

Tags: gradle, lottie, android-studio-3.5.1

Upgraded android studio to 3.5.1. Took fresh checkout of project and gradle sync started failing. Searched everywhere but could not find any proper solution. In logs can see error at line 97 of lottie react native android gradle-maven-push.gradle

Have tried downgrading gradle version, android studio version as well but still same error.

Gradle task defined in gradle-maven-push.gradle

```
task androidJavadocs(type: Javadoc) {
  source = android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
  classpath += project.files(android.getBootClasspath()
 .join(File.pathSeparator))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it working by changing the code to

```
task androidJavadocs(type: Javadoc) {
  source = android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
  classpath += project.files(android.getBootClasspath()
 .join(File.pathSeparator)) + configurations.implementation
}
```

Reference: https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-android/blob/master/lottie/build.gradle
The difference is that of configuration.implementation between what is downloaded in lottie's react native module's build.gradle and and specified in github link.